# Bug with bitcoinchain.com?

Tags: api, utxo, error

The bug is with https://bitcoinchain.com

Before I report it I would like to see if I can gain any additional clues as to what might be going on in order to assist their developers to get to the root of the problem quickly.

---

If I call their API like so:

https://api-r.bitcoinchain.com/v1/address/utxo/1KZnzTTfuxiyHUJdLqn3UnHyTVDN2UgeHU

then add up all of the utxo.amounts they gave me for the wallet in question I get `0.57944267`

But if you examine the wallet here https://blockchain.info/address/1KZnzTTfuxiyHUJdLqn3UnHyTVDN2UgeHU

you see that it really holds `1.15968995`

---

With a little digging I see at least two of the utxos txid/hash(s) where they have incorrectly got the wrong output:

https://blockchain.info/tx/37ff697bc958071e6f6dc180f9b80edda8f87ab0ca2ad5cd3753e8f65c38e463

> they have picked the wrong wallet address `1o69bsLaqaAM6R7bomaGVFT7uvGFvziTy`

and

https://blockchain.info/tx/a02d62638266fe5b9004e99a45d5eca0878ab5dae1d328aeece39672f44cc98eeece39672f44cc98e

> they have picked the wrong wallet addess `16tk4YEYpE6taGzZjkH9aiEApLLDR8UZL9`

Not every utxo has this mistake, so it could be ruled out that they are always picking the first output.

I would have thought that they should just be asking if the output address matches the queried address but if they were doing that then surely this bug would not exist!

**What other factors could cause this?**

Comment: They're also missing some outputs, like 056c445c8d6f67355c554f186200af3413de9cb3918a13e7e0bb1b2d0a7cc2a3.